# Is it possible to serve gzipped js/css files from a public CDN?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, gzip, cdn

According to [this article](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-minification-and-gzipping/), gzipping a minified file, can significantly reduce its size.

In case of my website, I have quite a few libraries which are served from a public CDN, for example I have included the following minified bootstrap files in my site:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

1. Is there any option to server the gzipped version of the above files from a public CDN?
2. If that's not an option, is it a good idea to gzip the above libraries and serve them from my own CDN (i.e. server them from CloudFront and set the option to compress the files)?

### Update

As per the comments, I have checked the content type and both bootstrap files are compressed.

bootstrap.min.js
[image]

bootstrap.min.css
[image]

Comment: its already encoded with brotli, not sure if gzip will help

Comment: Yeah, what Chris said.  Use your browser's developer tools to see that compression is already occurring.